# ion-input only allows one character to be entered at a time

Tags: angular, ionic2

On the landing page of my app I have an input box where a user needs to enter an ID to join an event. This has always been working without any issues, but now suddenly (without changing anything on that page) it only allows me to enter one character every time I focus the input box. (So if I deselect it and select it again, I can add another digit).

This only happens on iOS. In the browser and on Android it works as it should.

There are no errors in the console and I'm not changing the value of that variable programmatically anywhere.

page.ts

```
eventId: string;
```

page.html

```
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input type="tel" [(ngModel)]="eventId" placeholder="Event ID" clearInput></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

I really don't have any ideas what could cause such a behaviour, especially because I haven't changed that code in a long time.

I already spent more time on this issue that I would like to admit, maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you using ios simulator to check this behavior.

Comment: No, I'm using a real device.

Comment: what is clearInput doing on your tag

Comment: I think it adds a small "cancel" button at the end that clears the input. I found what caused the issue and wrote it in an answer.

Comment: wow... great to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an hour of digging through the commit history, I finally found what caused it. I was trying to suppress the magnifying glass using css:

```
* {
  -webkit-user-select: none; // Hide the "bubble" on press
}
```

This caused the issue. I don't really understand why, but at least it's working again now.

Comment: Exactly what happened to me too, this fixed it! Thanks! :D

Comment: You saved my time!